# Why android mediaPlayer callbacks implemented on UI thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, event-handling, android-mediaplayer

I have custom jni native player implementation. In fact, android app uses 2 players concurrently to speed-up next track preparation.

I noticed android's `android.media.MediaPlayer` implementation puts everything back to UI thread, and now I am trying to understand reason, possible benefits and whether it makes sense to do it same way. Currently all player events/callbacks from each jni player are returned to the java thread running that native player.

Please share your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: reverse question: whats wrong with UI thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the UI thread, it is completely defined in which thread the callback is called. It simplifies sequencing with other tasks that use the UI thread. As mentioned in the comments, if it weren't in the UI thread, it would be a random thread, or it would take an executor, making it more complex.

If instead of the UI thread you use your own thread, then the user has to do a lot of synchronization and post messages to the UI thread for those methods that require the UI thread; by already being on the UI thread, in the worst case, you will see a degraded performance if the callback is too long.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will accept, since there is no probably any better explanation.